# Best approach to remind boss about raise they mentioned?

Tags: professionalism, communication, salary, internship

I am an intern for a small software company, due to me not having a car, i often rely on coworkers or ride sharing services to get to work.

My boss found out and approached me, saying that he would put an extra amount on my paycheck to cover for the ride-sharing expenses as well as increasing my hourly rate by a few.

This was around a week ago, my boss is often very busy and so I think he forgot.

What's the best approach to remind him? I want to be as professional as possible as I have a great deal of respect for him and I wouldn't want to overstep my position as an intern.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a paycheck since he said he'd give you a raise?

Comment: @NotMe Yes, and our conversation was like two days before and nothing was updated. Next paycheck is coming in a few days, wondering if it's better to wait till that one to mention something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing it shortly after you see it wasn't on your check is perfect.  Trying to pre-emptively remind him is overly assertive, but as soon as you see it's not on the next check - ask him.

When you ask him - also ask him an estimated time you should see it and/or check in with him again.  I'd expect a knowledgeable boss to be able to say:  "I've put the request it... it has to go through --this-- set of steps before it gets finalized.  Given how long that takes, you can expect to see it by the paychek after X date... if that didn't happen, please let me know ASAP".  He may also be able to inform you if there's a way to back date the increase - meaning it'll be effective at some prior date and you get a lump sum to catch you up... not every company can do that, but it's lovely if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Email is good.   Just shoot him an email "Hey boss, was wondering if you'd had a chance to put in that raise you mentioned on such and such date?   I noticed it wasn't on my last check".

It's always good to have a response in writing.  If he responds with ANYTHING to indicate he agreed to it, it's hard to back out at that point and you can hold him to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just step into your boss' office and say something like:

> Hey Boss, I was just wondering if you happened to put in that raise
>   like we discussed.

Then see what he says.